# How to multiply by 3 a natural number given in binary, using combinatorial logic?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplication, combinatorial-logic

How to multiply by 3 a natural number in *n*-bit binary representation?

Adding *x* to 2*x*(*x* shifted one bit position to the higher significance positions) reads simple enough.
For a ripple carry adder, this requires 2 half adders and *n*-2 full adders.

But shouldn't knowing one summand is twice the other allow improvements?
Simplifications, even speed-up?

*Simple/cheap* and *fast* depend on the cost and timing model,
including the set of primitives to build from.
Other metrics include *power-delay product*.

Programmable logic basic building blocks ever changing,
I'm most comfortable with # of transistors in static CMOS,
say, no more than 7 channels in series (between any output and either power rail).
This would make the basic gate the And-Or-Invert gate starting from two transistors per input;
I suggest to include odd and even parity up to 5 inputs
(implementation options including pass transistors/gates).

Answer (score 4):

In [*Efficient Multiply-by-3 and Divide-by-3 Algorithms
and Their Fast Hardware Implementation*](https://ir.nctu.edu.tw/bitstream/11536/23816/1/000331343200023.pdf),
Chin-Long WEY, Ping-Chang JUI, and Gang-Neng SUNG
present a *Unit Cell for Addition*: UCA that has a simpler carry chain.
Comparing apples to apples
(full adders alternating between *inverted carry out* and *inverted carry in*),
it is the same speed as a full adder.
(I take the paper's timing analysis with a measure of salt
as well as their assumptions about building a ripple carry adder from FAs.)
The *sum* outputs being from "parity gates" in both alternatives,
the cost difference is nine transistors per UCA vs. twelve per FA (the availability of one more inverted bit per pair possibly making the 3-input parity implementation simpler, for a smaller difference, still).

[Carry chain link pair: full adder](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMkDMAmALItYeIJyJwBscaaIcECVlApgLSKIBQAZiCmBiOTymV6ZeEZAjDQ0LAO6dBiAOzE5FHAA5wLALIgM6JEt3EeiDDwhpIcdp2681GgaocikVqLhkreGCE94KFGAsAObe6H6CKCjKEMEcBBTMqiRI2LyIbuKSXmipahap+LG5+ZEUBZoASrr6lXoU+nG61OBtEtayiWlJ+M4awbLq9o52aC7BADJIZrypyXOxbWwAhgA2AM50lJrT3cZIfZxBSCCrm9vipcqKyv63mhy+Fi7+4xry7hKeXUcH3QtBjMeHk7mNUkDQUhxotgZohmANN1nocgl4UciYCNNAAnWpJQwNECVUSwFh4okPIkRNqIMmyfw0xl2eKonreBZoTJiDxSDhcEzEcpIIUZLK8rz+YreEmS+Sze4woECoT8OyIUXK+SE-QPLUVCBE2VDVKYQrKNCBR4iDTvWF2nDi75SE03QxQ4as4Z8e3CR0853XWwg1I0oHUx2Mx2QxFs73CVkY9L3dJwFBOnKyDFHJNonAKOFQ0wgq08ADCAGsmCx8-iDMoMAdhjwADWVoNMqLRyXgsEghO5WMaiyxg5TG0gJuxprLdZbHbh-Q0jCVMPo1d2Fd+btZuqGyrG3QH-eidJAshImEX7HnmEHa-YAbr0Q5yqWtGyOBHYuUI7v+GULM96zI+AFwCBV6zHa55HJUX5JGez7EtQsFxF48HBr+jQ7ke24odhaEcOBJhXt+MJchmnhEVBLgYQ6ohfJmE7dMMw4ASxLjehMNhqBq7JKEiqbpgGTECXCYmgUCYnSmJsocIEoiihJooUSJVGTsICwSekqmMT8k5WqBxCGbMQLGQaBkUNKrLEJp6TmeyunZPpGGVA5h7uRAslobItkmLBfHdECvE3AFNyIbuBLKCQoiGGZhmGBJcXoaKDwxRO54qbGCkZV4OVsTlnrod+QFDqZXhCkipWCR+Gn+RQW5ssEtZqCu9bEm+sblhWAA6AAOrCyElyitUiyV4qN7WTWGSBkhNbUPJNJKzTA2jEgthgOKIpm8FYeXEBoB5tR5Vo0hha4cKxKnzCp3J6XydUihADlsU5Eq+XZFCVeyZmaaKflNUhP6NUFxWqFaAPQRVp2OmJa6yNNsMHccPmWZhDkXY9Zpo9j-r3dDUU4wOHCQy4Dn0ZRLo46k5NWlJjo+oVsZScjNJwyyXghWyXNQxwPMuGJdqfM5VOkxohXcUNyPY4LdM2BL4vS5xDEi-tY3KILzPywzwiC36KvvY9+x+r4uyATwwH8CcEDnPOVzTNe94wjOmS25c1rXnajVC0k+NETCoEg1ewn40AA)
[image: Carry chain double link: full adder]
[Carry chain link pair: UCA](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMZICYaoOyYMxgByoBsAnCZiHBAlZQKYC0iiAUAGYir75JEQ5xUvakkgIUYVO07dOqACwgBQ1ApCLEYqJJYB3JYKSYiBoYhJCwe00gs30PKwFkb5oTnwa+4TmOlceAPtZDS0JKX1lTnl+QyxLFgBzGzxFKJwcEwgrfSDEbyDVRSsON2FOOBN8kU1xaAiKqsQVSqR5YutUVuZ3Qx7wayj+ofaB-TLq2xVZHKmZQNkgqwAZIyq7Zp4yiEQQNgBDABsAZzpKAdXEY0ouJFvBRx8Dk7PxTu7rrvWE3O67IbsszK8hw0x4IJ+ckU8hIJiKN0cnRCsPmlG8VmSUTg1yifEeGMalE+rTxPlmXwRNgeY0J1IpcFGJTmlQg9O8oTqOhcWNuHkULJ8qD8HCCAqx7NEnIaPJ4WMZg0McGaVNuTKCMJMUQ151q2mlhnasoN+Gy-hCoJsEJ1YXq1mBFrKSzt10dam2nTddnh8PJam9izUQOudLU1N90JR6pRQLsVrKApjZm8E2VKzm-TKJp8u2ep3OacyPBRhZAWeyeyOebe+ittYtCes8iIEZM1O1sxl6mblNmTcU8JDHRr3eB3Z9CrMsZHgMbFrrYIGHDb9dj9cleuscFj8h4W6EO9NACVKLGYCBmxAYuXLyJr8LKdq9+oUQhdeFN3YlUIn2GP9-7p+8pLvc3g-hKb62i4P63EQrRhr4cDSFaAqPuBNo6DWL63I+8qYa2AH-oiySPtc2qkqayQ-sGdjkTSbZYbu6KNt22p9j2s77vW2EWr2KLxhsM54Wsz7fDSVqircTo1g67IWk6x5Pv0F5IKmPgxPmZJ+PoinKopuEiSp34bKmjZ8cq2qIEB6gyZefGgeu77abckyDgMlH-GA-L-JkZJ-tE1BepgCTAQsu5eiEDmQSek5CLBomslp0XMl6BB0Rs1ExYulIDl6agchuIXlIp9kQToxH5EoPnyBVJamhwJagpeNXoOokUYeoFXqjVnliZ1QUdXCMzSCWFLVXCcFtQ0Y2GQN-m9YN4JyUNkR9OZFX9B2RBFpqW2EptgStA1LW9ut5lmZCWo1QaZ4dtdAX7jdfnTU+V4DEAA)
[image]

Comment: For an utterly stupefying result about *division* by 3, see [How to divide a natural number given in binary by 3](/a/701802/274544).